# The proof of decay rate of Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have tried to prove the followng.

If $f$ satisfies the Holder condition with exponent $\alpha\in(0,1]$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$, then $c_n(f)=\mathcal{O}(\vert n \vert ^{-\alpha})$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ where
$$
c_n(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx.
$$

At first, I assumed that $f$ is a periodic function and proved this statement as follows.

$$2\pi c_n(f)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(y)e^{-iny}dy=\int_{-\pi+\pi/n}^{\pi+\pi/n}
f(y)e^{-iny}dy=e^{-i\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+\pi/n)e^{-inx}dx$$

So we have

$$
\begin{align}
\vert -4\pi c_n(f) \vert &= \left\vert \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x+\pi/n)-f(x))e^{-inx}dx \right\vert \newline
&\leq 2\pi\sup_{x,x+\pi/n\in[-\pi,\pi]}\left\vert f(x+\pi/n)-f(x) \right\vert \newline
&\leq C(\pi/\vert n \vert)^\alpha
\end{align}
$$

But if $f$ is not periodic, then how can I prove the above statement? At least if $f$ is defined on any interval $[a,b]$ and if $f(a)=f(b)$ then we can extend $f$ as a periodic function and there exists another periodic function $g$ defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$ whose Fourier coefficients are same as those of $f$; so this is not the case.

Comment: You can extend the function to the periodic one. Then the function does not satisfy the Holder inequality on $[\pi,\pi+\pi/n],$ due to possible discontinuity t $\pi.$  In your last formula you can estimate the integral over $[\pi-\pi/n,\pi]$ by $2Mn^{-1},$ where $M$ is the maximal value of $|f|.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc So just use the boundedness of $f$? which can be derived from the Holder condition in bounded domain... I missed it. Thank you.

Comment: The Holder condition on $[-\pi,\pi]$ implies continuity, therefore the boundedness as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to post my own answer to this question since I fully resolve this issue.

In order to factor out $n^{-\alpha}$, we express the integral as a sum of finite $n>0$ integrals as follows:
\begin{align}
c_n(f) &= \frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\int_{a+\frac{(b-a)j}{n}}^{a+\frac{(b-a)(j+1)}{n}} f(x) e^{inx} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\int_{a+\frac{(b-a)j}{n}}^{a+\frac{(b-a)(j+1)}{n}} \left(f(x) - f\left(a+\frac{(b-a)j}{n}\right)\right) e^{inx} dx
\end{align}
This can be still done as $n\rightarrow\infty$ by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. Then we have
\begin{align}
\vert c_n(f) \vert &\leq \frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\int_{a+\frac{(b-a)j}{n}}^{a+\frac{(b-a)(j+1)}{n}} \left| f(x) - f\left(a+\frac{(b-a)j}{n}\right) \right| dx \\
&\leq \frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{b-a}{n}C\left|\frac{b-a}{n}\right|^\alpha \\
&\leq C|n|^{-\alpha}
\end{align}
using the Holder condition of $f$.